# unable to open new window from code behind with Response.Write or ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code:

I create the script:

```
Dim redirect As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('~/PrintOrder.aspx?OrderNumber=" & Me.ViewState("OrderNumber") & "', '_blank');</script>"
```

I tried:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "openWindow", redirect)
```

I've also tried:

```
Response.Write(redirect)
```

A breakpoint confirms that the string `redirect` is created properly.  The browser is NOT blocking popups, yet absolutely nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Comment: When you check the page source in the browser, is the code you expect there?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?

Comment: No errors, the page that the code is being written to is refreshed after the javascript is written to it. Hmmm, raises the question, is the page refreshed BEFORE the code is executed.  I'll have to look into that.  Thanks for the hint. Lol ....

Comment: @PrescottChartier JavaScript does not process the `~` in `~/PrintOrder.aspx`.

Comment: @Andrew Morton  I didn't think so, I was just grasping at straws.  I'm investigating the refresh issue mentioned in my comment above.  I now believe that the page may be refreshing before the code can be executed.

Comment: @PrescottChartier What event is intended to open the window, e.g. does the user click a button?

Comment: @Andrew Mordon - No, on creation of the order so it can be filled by pickers in the warehouse.  I was able to resolve the issue, turns out the page was being refreshed BFEORE the code could be executed.  I stopped the refresh and all works as one would expect.  I will now refresh the page and THEN send the code to print the order on the warehouse printer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
Dim redirect As String = "<script type='text/javascript'> window.open('PrintOrder.aspx?OrderNumber=" & Me.ViewState("OrderNumber") & "', '', 'left=100,top=100,height=350px,width=400px,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes', false); </script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "openWindow", redirect);
```

Comment: The problem I was having is that the page was being refreshed BEFORE the code was executed.  It wasn't the line of code I was using.  When I stopped the page from refreshing, the window opened as expected.  Thanks for the suggestion though.